# Anime where a kid has a small humanoid magical companion who has a round shape and wings

Tags: story-identification, magic, anime

Over 10 years ago, I saw this anime, so there are some things that I don’t remember anymore, only that there was this teenage kid that had a small magical companion in a green suit and small wings. There was also a girl that went to the same school as the protagonist and she had another magical companion, but this one had a black suit.

The humanoids from the anime I’m talking about had almost an entirely round shape, they looked like flying balls with a head and wings. And their suits were entirely of the color I mentioned before —the protagonist’s had one color blue and the girl had one color black—.

Comment: No, it’s not Angelic Layer. The humanoids from the anime I’m talking about had almost an entirely round shape, they looked like flying balls with a head and wings. And their suits were entirely of the color I mentioned before —the protagonist’s had one color blue and the girl had one color black—.

Comment: It's better to add any new info directly on the post by [edit]ing it so that everything is on the question body, not fragmented on the comment :)

Comment: Yeah, you’re right. Thank you. I already edit it.

Answer (score 3):

I think it was called [Mirmo de Pon!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirmo!). I remember watching it when I was a kid.

> Over 10 years ago,

The original airing in Japan was from 2002 to 2005.

> had almost an entirely round shape, they looked like flying balls with a head and wings.

The Muglox, the magical companions in Mirmo de Pon!, indeed have a very round shape. They don't have wings, but there are two possibilities for misremembering Muglox to have wings. For one, Mirmo, the Muglox that gives the series its name, twice uses an [angel outfit](https://mirmo.fandom.com/wiki/Mirmo#Outfits). But there is a more likely possibility: Certain Muglox' are able to transform their human companions into [fairies](https://mirmo.fandom.com/wiki/Katie_Minami#Season_Special) -- which *have* wings

> the protagonist's had one color blue and the girl had one color black--.

[Mirmo](https://mirmo.fandom.com/wiki/Mirmo) is the Muglox of the protagonist and has "a blue hat, yellow hair, blue apparel,". [Yatch](https://mirmo.fandom.com/wiki/Yatch), Mirmos rival and the Muglox of the protagonists rival is usually dressed in red with black, and has black hair. Moreover he is described as having "ninja-like weapons and looks" and thus may have appearances clad completely in black.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Could it perhaps be [Angelic Layer](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=400)?

> Plot Summary: 12-year-old Misaki Suzuhara has just gotten involved in
>   Angelic Layer, a battling game using electronic dolls called angels.
>   Even as a newbie, Misaki shows advanced skills as she meets new
>   friends and enters Angelic Layer tournaments to fight the greatest
>   Angelic Layer champions of the nation.

Comment: Can you possibly provide more information (e.g., author, publication date, etc)? Can you find a description of it and provide quotes that would support your suggestion?